# ImportError: cannot import name 'CharsetMetaAttributeValue'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc='''
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

print(soup.prettify())
```

That's my code. It's very easy, still I'm encountering the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'CharsetMetaAttributeValue'

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: can you run "from bs4.element import CharsetMetaAttributeValue" without errors? If not something is wrong with your install. Also look for naming conflicts.

Comment: This code has no issue. Try reinstalling bs4 module, it may solve the problem. or try lxml parser instead of html.parser which is by default.